# action-default package in Struts 2

Tags: java, inheritance, configuration, struts2, package

Is there a package like `action-default` associated with Struts2 ?

I am not sure which jar(struts-core or plugins) it comes from but it was residing in my `struts.xml` for years. We had used struts-core-2.1.8.

I updated the struts version to 2.3.8 and struts started complaining,

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2-prepare
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.init(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: Parent package is not defined: action-default - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildPackageContext(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:660)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:508)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:290)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
```

I couldn't find any references for `action-default` package. Could anybody please help me figure out what is available in `action-default` package and the alternatives in Struts 2.3.8.

**EDIT:**

I couldn't post the complete `struts.xml`, it's too long. The package declaration is as below,

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,jfreechart-default,json-default,action-default">
```

Artifact Id of Struts related jars used:

> 1. struts2-core 2.1.8
> 2. struts2-convention-plugin 2.1.8
> 3. struts2-spring-plugin 2.1.8
> 4. struts2gwtplugin 0.2.1
> 5. struts2-jfreechart-plugin 2.1.6
> 6. struts2-jquery-plugin 3.5.0
> 7. struts2-json-plugin 2.1.8.1

With all the above mentioned jars struts didn't complain about the "action-default" package.

After updating the following jars to version 2.3.8, struts starts complaining that the package is missing,

> 1. struts2-core 2.3.8
> 2. struts2-convention-plugin 2.3.8
> 3. struts2-spring-plugin 2.3.8
> 4. struts2-json-plugin 2.3.8

Comment: Post your `struts.xml`. Post the version of all the Struts2 JARs you have in your project

Comment: @AndreaLigios, edited my post to make the configurations more clear

Comment: Marking Roman C's answer as correct though as it didn't provide me exact/direct answer for the question, the tool he suggested is so cool and helps analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such package name `action-default` in the Struts default configuration the package name is `struts-default`. Change the name of the package which your package extends.

Comment: I could also see that there is no such package definition available in all the jars. Please see my latest edit and could you please provide substantiate proof that how it was working in v2.1.8. Thanks for your reply

Comment: You can do it yourself, check the configuration file that inside the jar and find packages with the name or better add config-browser plugin and check the configuration online.

Comment: It appears in some random places over the web, and only one time in Struts2 doc: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/action-configuration.html `<package name="Hello" extends="action-default">`. It could be an error... or it could have been existed in old libraries and not anymore, but it seems strange. **+1** to the question, for being interesting. Your boss will give you **-1** for having used for years the wrong package :D `struts-default` is what you want.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, Thanks for the comment. As it seems "action-default" is not a valid package, I will remove it. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

i ALSO GOT THE SAME ISSUE BUT ITS WORKING FINE WITH BELOW LISTED JAR ,

commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar 
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang3-3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar 
freemarker-2.3.22.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.19.jar
struts2-core-2.3.30.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.3.30.jar
xwork-core-2.3.30.jar

MY STRUTS.XML LOOKS LIKE AS ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" extends="json-default">
    <action name="angularAction" class="com.action.AngularAction">
        <result type="json">
          <param name="root">personData</param>
          <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
          <param name="noCache">true</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

- REGARDS,SUBODH K SINGH